# How to track whatsapp online status of unsaved contacts programatically

Tags: whatsapp

Over searching, I found various solutions such as -

1 - Web Scraping using selenium but that is a very inefficient way to track multiple contacts

2 - Using store object. That was one of the best ways to **track WhatsApp online status for multiple numbers** but after the recent update, WhatsApp has stopped showing the online status of unsaved, unchatted contacts due to which all these methods have failed.

but I wonder how various applications like -
. https://chatwatch.net/
. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.familog&hl=en_IN&gl=US
are still able to track the online status ?

Comment: I tried reverse engineering as well but it seems they are performing the main tracking logic code in their server and updating client side with sockets or FCM

Answer (score 0):

After 6-7 December update, you can't.

Your ways:

- Mock the XMPP Protocol
- Create a real device (like emulator or android phone) and get the data on client.
- Create a real device (like emulator or android phone) and get the data from Whatsapp Web.
- Mock the Whatsapp Application.
- Man in the middle attack to whatsapp application.

These ways deprecated because after 6/7 December Security Update if you don't have whatsapp chat history with this number, you can not subscribe his presence.

After today, if you want to track someone you have to chat with him. If you message the person you will follow before following, this will be detected by whatsapp and you will get banned.

Comment: so how many applications like . https://chatwatch.net/ . https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.familog&hl=en_IN&gl=US are doing ?

Comment: Still they can't, I always talking with whatsapp tracker app owners; they don't know. Some of whatsapp trackers still alive. But they don't have any difference. We will see in the long term, what was the difference. If you can check the google play link, you can see "it's not working!" comments.

Comment: Yes, they aren't.You are right. What they were doing earlier ? I guess they were tweaking Whatsapp business API ?

Comment: As I mentioned on main reply they have 5 different ways for to do this. Easiest way is get data from whatsapp web sockets. Business API not a good idea.

Comment: Well the above stated ways i doubt as all these methods require Whatsapp to show 'Online' status and even its backend mechanism stopped fetching online status of contacts that arent saved or unchatted before.
You can try in whatsapp by seeing any online status of unsved , unchatted contact.It didnt show.It stopped showing 15-20 days ago.

Comment: These application have started to work from today

Comment: Any idea on this ??